# Formatting dates as financial year in DC.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Hopefully a very simple question.  I am displaying some data using DC.js and Crossfilter and need to plot annual totals based on the financial year range 1st April - 31st March, i.e. the 2015 total will cover the date range 1st April 2015 - 31st March 2016.

I have created a year dimension as below though this is based on each year covering 1st January - 31st December.  I cannot find anything obvious through searching the D3/DC/Crossfilter documentation.

The date value in the csv file being imported is in the format YYYYMMDD.

```
var yearFormat = d3.time.format("%Y");

var yearDim = cf.dimension(function (d) {
    return yearFormat(d.myDateField);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you're making your dimension on solely the year part of the date. You would need to extend your yearFormat function to return the correct financial year number.

```
var yearFormat = function(date){
    if (date.getMonth < 3){
        return d3.time.format("%Y") - 1;
    } else {
        return d3.time.format("%Y");
    }
}
```

Comment: edited because `getMonth` is [zero-based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)